# Script error in ie7,ie8 and firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript

In a website that I am currently working on , I get a collection of data from back-end dynamically and populate to Jcarousel when  the page loads. The site is working fine in chrome , ie9 and ff 21 but it throws script error which says "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly" . Has any one faced similar issue? Is it because the Jarousel cannot accommodate huge amount of data or is it some thing wrong with my code? I should also say that this issue is spasmodic !

I saw this post http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/03/04/How-to-prevent-Stop-running-this-script-message-in-browsers but I already have so much of timers set in the page. Is there any other alternate solution?

Appreciate suggestions .Thanks in advance

Comment: Where have you found all these ancient browsers?

Comment: From treasures, the hidden one

Comment: @Teemu: in certain companies, users are forced to use that since their IT departments stick to policies, we also are facing things like that and you have to deal with it. Going the "We are not supporting IE < 9" way is not an option in these cases.

Comment: :) That's client's requirement !!

Comment: Why don't you serve a simpler layout for the browsers that can't handle the load of `Jcarousel`?

Comment: @AxelAmthor Yep, I know, I'm working for a company which is partly sticked to IE8. But FF3.6, Mozilla has dropped all support to it, and states: Using FF3.6 is a significant security risk. (I'm not claimimg using older IEs wouldn't be...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ie7 and 8 are crap. Their's no silver bullet to deal with this error, unless you do not exactly know what script/loop/ajax/wtf.. is causing the error. You need to debug that in depth in order to find out what's going on, sorry, no better advise.